# Problemas con Update PHP, utilizando PDO

Tags: php, bootstrap, phpmyadmin, pdo, post

Muy buenas, hasta ahora estoy elaborando un **CRUD** sencillo, en el que utilizo **PDO** para utilizar la base de datos. Tengo construido todas las actividades que puede hacer el CRUD menos la de actualizar, ya que me esta dando problemas que no se encontrar.
Hasta ahora he podido creer que tengo un problema con el id del producto, ya que lo llamo por GET desde la página principal **"listado.php"** pero no lo actualiza a través del formulario del producto que quiero actualizar, que utilizo como método POST.

Os dejo por aquí la página principal, que como pueden ver llamo en el boton de editar al producto en cuestión de su id, que me lleva a otra página donde se encuentra el formulario:

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    <title>Proyecto DSW</title>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>Gestión de productos</h1>

    <div class="d-grid gap-2">
        <a href="crear.php" class="btn btn-success btn-block boton">Crear producto</a>
    </div>


    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
        <tr class="table-dark">
            <th class="detalle">Detalle</th>
            <th class="codigo">Codigo</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Acciones</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
        include "conexion.php";
        
        $pdo = Conexion::conectar();
        $sql = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM productos ORDER BY id DESC");
        // $conexion = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        foreach ($sql as $resultado) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td><a href='detalle.php?id=".$resultado['id']."' class='btn btn-info btn-block botonInfo'>Detalle</a></td>";
            echo "<td class='codigo'><b>".$resultado['id']."</b></td>";
            echo "<td><b>".$resultado['nombre']."<b></td>";
            echo "<td>
                <a href='editar.php?id=".$resultado['id']."' class='btn btn-warning btn-block botonExtra'>Actualizar</a>
                <a href='borrar.php?id=".$resultado['id']."' class='btn btn-danger btn-block botonExtra'>Borrar</a></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "</table";

        }
        Conexion::desconectar();
        ?>


        <script src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

La otra página en cuestión es **editar.php**, que es de donde surgen los problemas:

```
<?php
require "conexion.php";

// $id = null;
if (!empty($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
}

if (!empty($_POST)) {

    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $nombre_corto = $_POST['nombre_corto'];
    $pvp = $_POST['pvp'];
    $select = $_POST['familia'];
    $descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];

    $pdo = Conexion::conectar();
    $sql = "UPDATE productos  SET nombre = ?, nombre_corto = ?, descripcion = ?, pvp = ?, familia = ? WHERE id = ?;";
    $conexion = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    // echo "$sql";
    // echo "$conexion";
    $conexion->execute([$nombre, $nombre_corto, $descripcion, $pvp, $select, $id]);
    echo "$conexion";
    $nuevaURL = "listado.php";
    Conexion::desconectar();
    header('Location: ' . $nuevaURL);
    
}
$pdo = Conexion::conectar();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM productos where id = ?;";
$conexion = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$conexion->execute([$id]);
$data = $conexion->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$nombre = $data->nombre;
$nombre_corto = $data->nombre_corto;
$pvp = $data->pvp;
$select = $data->familia;
$descripcion = $data->descripcion;

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style2.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Crear producto</title>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>Actualizar Producto</h1>

    <div class="grid estilodiv">
        <form class="row g-3" method="post" action="editar.php" id="formularioActualizar" autocomplete="off">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label class="form-label">Nombre</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" value="<?php echo !empty($nombre) ? $nombre : ''; ?>">

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label class="form-label">Nombre Corto</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre_corto" placeholder="Nombre Corto" value="<?php echo !empty($nombre_corto) ? $nombre_corto : ''; ?>">

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label class="form-label">Precio (€)</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="pvp" placeholder="Precio" value="<?php echo !empty($pvp) ? $pvp : ''; ?>">

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label class="form-label">Familia</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="familia">
                    <?php
                    $pdoSelect = Conexion::conectar();
                    $sqlSelect = $pdoSelect->query("SELECT * FROM familias");
                    $sqlSelect->execute();
                    while ($data = $sqlSelect->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
                        echo '<option value="' . $data->cod . '">' . $data->nombre . '</option>';
                    }
                    Conexion::desconectar();
                    ?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label class="form-label">Descripción</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" name="descripcion" cols="20" rows="10" placeholder="Ingrese una descripción..."><?php echo !empty($descripcion) ? $descripcion : ''; ?></textarea>

            </div>
            <!-- <input type='hidden' name='id' value=$id> -->
            <div class="d-grid gap-2">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Actualizar</button>
            </div>

            <div class="d-grid gap-2">
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-success">Limpiar</button>
            </div>

            <div class="d-grid gap-2">
                <a href="listado.php" class="btn btn-secondary">Volver</a>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <?php
    // Conexion::desconectar();
    ?>
</body>

</html>
```

Me da errores de idefenida la variable "id", pero esta no se como definirla, ya que lo intento hacer mediante un campo *imput hidden* pero no se como hacerlo. Muchas gracias.

Os dejo el error que me muestra al hacer `echo "$conexion";`
El FATAL ERROR, es sencillo, es por utilizar esta linea de codigo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto:

```
<!-- <input type='hidden' name='id' value=$id> -->
```

debes cambiarlo por esto:

```
<input type='hidden' name='id' value='<?=$id?>'>
```

por que por un lado lo estás comentando y no se interpreta cuando usas el par `<!--` y `-->` y por el otro, no encierras entre comillas el **value** ni tampoco dejas que el PHP lo interprete, pues esta fuera de las instrucciones en PHP, por lo tanto, de forma abreviada lo puedes poner así:

```
<?=$id?>
```

que vendría a ser lo mismo que:

```
<?php echo $id; ?>
```

pero más corto.

Comment: Perfecto muchísimas gracias, era lo que necesitaba, ya me funciona correctamente el update

Comment: Me alegro :-)  Recuerda aceptar la respuesta para que no quede pendiente eternamente, gracias. En [este enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) aprenderás a aceptar respuestas. Te recomiendo también que hagas el [tour] para aprender la mecánica del sitio, gracias.